# Is there a way to skip spaces for certain rules but not others?

Tags: antlr4

My grammar contains the following:

```
assignment
: ID ASSIGN expr
;

expr
 : MINUS expr                 #unaryMinusExpr
 | NOT expr                   #notExpr
 | expr MULT expr             #multExpr
 | expr DIV expr              #divExpr
 | expr PLUS expr             #plusExpr
 | expr MINUS expr            #minusExpr
 | expr LTEQ expr             #lteqExpr
 | expr GTEQ expr             #gteqExpr
 | expr LT expr               #ltExpr
 | expr GT expr               #gtExpr
 | expr NEQ expr              #neqExpr
 | expr EQ expr               #eqExpr
 | expr AND expr              #andExpr
 | expr OR expr               #orExpr
 | function     #functionExpr
 | atom                       #atomExpr
 ;

 function
: ID OPAR (parameter (',' parameter)*)? CPAR
;

parameter
: STRING #stringParameter
| expr   #exprParameter
;

atom
 : OPAR expr CPAR #parExpr
 | (INT | FLOAT)  #numberAtom
 | (TRUE | FALSE) #booleanAtom
 | ID             #idAtom
 ;

OR : '||';
AND : '&&';
EQ : '==';
NEQ : '!=';
GT : '>';
LT : '<';
GTEQ : '>=';
LTEQ : '<=';
PLUS : '+';
MINUS : '-';
MULT : '*';
DIV : '/';
NOT : '!';
OPAR : '(';
CPAR : ')';
OBRACE : '{';
CBRACE : '}';
ASSIGN : '=';

TRUE : 'true';
FALSE : 'false';
IF : 'if';
ELSE : 'else';

ID
 : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*
 ;

SPACE
 : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
 ;
```

The issue is that ID needs to be able to also contain MINUS, PLUS, etc. This means that I won't be able to tell when I have just an ID (this-isandid) or ID (this) MINUS ID (isandid).

What we'd like to do is to not skip the spaces around the operators in the expr, but otherwise skip spaces for all other rules. Is there a way to do that? I.e. we force the user to put spaces around operators when they really mean an expression as opposed to an ID containing e.g. MINUS.

I.e.

a-b is an ID

a - b is a minusExpr

a- b, a -b is an error

Or is there another way to allow e.g. MINUS in an ID and be able to tell the difference between an ID and a minusExpr?

Comment: So a `-` or `+` inside an `ID` is *always* part of the identifier? The input `a-b` and `a - b` are clear, but could you edit your post and explain how the following input should be tokenized: `a -b`, `a- b` ?

Comment: Can't you simply make minus and plus part of your ID lexer rule? ANTLR by default tokenizes greedily, so it should do the right thing with that.

Comment: The necessary question is how do 'you' recognize when a dash is used as a MINUS or a HYPHEN?  If, for example, it must be MINUS because both 'this' and 'isandid' are variables such that only MINUS makes sense, then the decision must wait until you build the symbol table.  But, that is me guessing.  Independent of the Antlr grammar implementation, what are the criteria you use to decide between MINUS and HYPHEN?  And, same analysis for PLUS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to avoid conditional consideration of whitespace in the parser rules by modifying the `ID` rule within the lexer. Allow a `-` to appear in an `ID`, provided it is not at the beginning or end of the identifier.

```
ID
  : [a-zA-Z_]
    ( '-'? [a-zA-Z_0-9]
    )*
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using lexer modes. There would be one mode (or default mode) where the spaces are skipped, and the other one where they would not be skipped.